# Maven command line parameter "-B"

Tags: maven, command-line

Does anyone know what the -B maven parameter does?
Sample use:

```
maven clean install -B -U -e
```

(I'm seeing this in a legacy Jenkins job config)
Thanks

Comment: -1 http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mvn/

Comment: Your local install would include man pages as well. There are many sites which simply publish their man pages as a web service (helpful for googling etc, as well as linking, like I did).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`-B` is a shorthand for `--batch-mode`. It allows you to [perform a release in a non-interactive way](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html). Having said that, using is in conjunction with the `clean` and `install` targets seems redundant to me as these goals are non-interactive by nature.

Comment: One additional difference using `-B` is that maven doesn't print `Progress` information on downloads. Those likely can spam your log file and therefor batch mode is also a worthy accessory when logging the output of a maven execution into a file.

Comment: With option -B my logs colored in IDEA terminal (asii escape symbols treated well)